# How to read and write Mac drives on Windows

Tags: windows, mac, external-hard-drive, hfs

I have some external hard drives that are *Mac OS Extended (Journaled)* formatted. What software can you recommend for working with those drives when under Windows? Do you have any experience with this?

Would be best if the software is free, but it doesn't have to be.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: @Charles: I have, to the ones where I have gotten an answer. But I'll go through them again if you want.

Answer (score 7):

For read only access you can try [hfs explorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/)

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: @SurrealDreams fixed

Answer (score 5):

You can install Apple bootcamp drivers (no official download links but you can find it on other sites) on a non-Apple machine. This will install HFS+ (the other name for Mac OS Extended) drivers for Windows.

*[Originally found on MacRumors forum, detailed instructions here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=783063)*

Comment: Interesting! Will have to try that out.

Comment: Svish, did you have a chance to test this solution? I'm curious to know if it works

Comment: No, but I really want to! My problem is that I'm missing the bootcamp drivers as I don't know anyone that has Bootcamp... and things have been a bit busy so haven't found time to search for them other places =/

Answer (score 3):

For those with Windows 7, drivers can be found using Apple KB: TS3172

http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3172

Comment: When trying to install on Windows 7 got - "This utility was not intended for this operating system"

Answer (score 2):

Seems like [MediaFour MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/) is the recommended one from various places. If anyone has any good and free alternatives or just other alternatives, I'd like to know about those though :)

> Along with the ability to read and write to Mac disks and volumes, you can also create Mac disks for easy file transfers and backups. The built-in MacDrive Disk Manager gives you the power to partition, format, analyze and repair disks, while the newly revamped CD/DVD Creator allows you to burn Mac CDs and DVDs.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL830). It works just great. They are the official Apple´s driver set. It works with latest format (End 2012).

Comment: Note: Only works for XP

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered going in the opposite direction?

NTFS on OSX

This is what i do.  Any External Drive that i connect to my OSX machine that i plan to also use with Windows i make the volume an NTFS volume. osxFUSE(googlecode) will allow you to write EXT3&4,ZFS,NTFS, and basicly any Filesystem on your MAC.

http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/

Comment: If they were my drives I totally would :p

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've used MacDrive and its probably the only one around that works good.

Its sometimes buggy though, last I used was up to November last year. Don't know about the latest updates.

I've since changed all my drives back to NTFS, since Snow Leopard has (hidden) native support for writing NTFS files. (Google that - fstab ntfs mac) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am using HVF_Explorer with a WIN32 system.
HVF_Explorer does a pretty good job, and its free.

Greetings!

Comment: Hasn't been updated since 1999, so I doubt it can work on journaled HFS partition

Readme doesn't mention support for WinXP (stops at Win98)

Comment: Thats right, it will only work with hfs and not hfs+ , SORRY!
Support for Windows XP SP2 and SP3 is OK.