# How to mount a mobile hard drive of Mac OS to windows?

Tags: mac, filesystems, hfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read and write Mac drives on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/138653/how-to-read-and-write-mac-drives-on-windows)

My friend has a 500G mobile hard drive which he used with his Mac.  Part of the drive is used to install a Windows system.

Recently he lost his Mac but he had the hard drive.  Now the problem is Windows could not recognize the mobile hard drive but we don't have a Mac on hand.

Is possible to read the data on his hard drive on Windows?

Comment: ah! the mac asks the pc for help ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/). I believe there is a free trial version available.